# How to Convert decimal in java?

Tags: java, android

I want to convert 7.08585576113109E-4 to 7.09  using Java. Please help me. I want this value for using google map. i used

```
    double dist = 7.08585576113109E-4;    
    double km=dist/1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    int kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter=dist%1000;
    int  meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
```

Comment: you know `7.08585576113109E-4`is actually something like `0.000709`?

Comment: Sorry i don't know. please help.

Comment: the E-4 is equal to *10^-4

Comment: This code snippet does not make much sense. What is your ultimate goal? Convert a distance expressed in km to meters?

Comment: Take a look at [DecimalFormat]8http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) there is an example for parsing decimal values like yours (#.###E-4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
double kms = TotalDistance / 1000 ;
String a = new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(kms);
```

Hope it will help you.